# How to set timezone of Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

Now all the time of my google groups is PDT, but I want it be GMT +8. Does google groups support timezone configuration or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the timezone.

[Google Groups FAQ](http://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-groups-faq#changegrouptimezone)

[image]